# Possible race condition when enabling multithreading

Tags: optaplanner

Suppose I have a slight variant of the cloud balancing problem, in which the `Process` has not just one weight, but a map of (positive) weights, such as

```
Map<Long, Long> groupMap = new HashMap<>();
```

where the the key is specific to my domain and the value is the weight.

On the class `Computer` (still referring to the cloud balancing example) I have a shadow variable `hist` which is also a `(Hash)Map<Long, Long>`, and a custom listener updating `hist`:

```
public class HistListener implements VariableListener {
    @Override
    public void beforeVariableChanged(ScoreDirector scoreDirector, Object o) {
        Process p = (Process) o;
        if (p.getComputer() != null) { 

            Computer kc = p.getComputer();

            //update hist Map
            scoreDirector.beforeVariableChanged(kc, "hist");
            for (Map.Entry<Long, Long> entrySet:k.getGroupMap().entrySet()){
                kc.getHist().put(entrySet.getKey(), kc.getHist().get(entrySet.getKey()) - k.getGroupMap().get(entrySet.getKey()));
            }
            scoreDirector.afterVariableChanged(kc, "hist");
        }
    }
```

and pretty much the same for `afterVariableChanged` just with reversed sign.

I annotate both `Process` and `Computer` as `@PlanningEntity` and register them in the `solverConfig`.

There are no constraints, so the solver should be able to assign the `computer`s to the `process`es arbitrarily. As a result, I expect `hist` only to have natural numbers (incl. 0) as values.

When running it with `<moveThreadCount>NONE</moveThreadCount>`, this is indeed the case:

```
<"Computer"+computer.id: hist>

Computer0: {0=0, 1=0, 2=20, 3=0, 4=10, 5=20, 6=0, 7=10, 8=10, 9=20}
Computer1: {0=0, 1=10, 2=0, 3=0, 4=10, 5=0, 6=10, 7=0, 8=0, 9=0}
Computer2: {0=0, 1=0, 2=0, 3=0, 4=0, 5=0, 6=0, 7=0, 8=0, 9=0}
```

When running ***exactly*** the same code with `<moveThreadCount>AUTO</moveThreadCount>`, I partially get negative values in `hist`:

```
Computer0: {0=0, 1=-20, 2=30, 3=0, 4=-40, 5=50, 6=-10, 7=30, 8=40, 9=150}
Computer1: {0=0, 1=-40, 2=-20, 3=0, 4=-90, 5=-50, 6=-40, 7=-20, 8=-20, 9=-30}
Computer2: {0=0, 1=80, 2=-20, 3=0, 4=30, 5=-30, 6=50, 7=0, 8=-20, 9=-50}
```

This discrepancy disappears when I refactor the keys of `groupMap` on `process` and those of `hist` on `computer` as individual shadow variables.

The `trace` logs suggest a race condition, where several threads access `hist` simultaneously. (According the Oracle docs, I only need a `synchronizedMap` implementation if the map is *structurally changed*, i.e., if keys are added or removed - I'm not doing that.)

The use of a `Map` as a shadow variable greatly enhances the flexibility of my solution, it would be great if this were supported with multithreading. I know I could probably fix *this* very simply example with an appropriate `ConstraintProvider`. My *actual* problem is *much* more complex than this and is not amenable to be treated with `ConstraintProvider`s.

**Question:** Is it possible to have a `Map` based structure as a shadow variable in a multithreading context?

If it is not possible , I recommend adding a short note in the docs of optaplanner 8.29.0.Final (the version I'm using).

I had a look at questions regarding `List`s as `PlanningVariable`s in optaplanner, but I don't see how these questions relate to mine.

Comment: Probably unrelated, but make sure you're not using 8.29.0.Final - it had a race condition regression that is fixed in 8.30.Final and later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to have a Map based structure as a shadow variable in a multithreading context?

Yes, because each move thread in a multithreading context has it's own `ScoreDirector` and own `workingSolution` internally. From a shadow variable's point of view and that map, it's single threaded.

**What can mess this up?**

- Bad `@PlanningId`'s in your dataset so the Move.rebase() operations go wrong. Duplicate IDs or lack of IDs. OptaPlanner detects most of these. Unlikely that this is your problem.
- Incomplete planning cloning in your model. That's probably it. This will also cause issues you haven't seen yet in a single threaded context, especially when the last working solution greatly differs from the last best found solution when the termination runs out. FULL_ASSERT should detect those, but they might not occur on every run...

*Each move thread has their own `workingSolution` internally.* That's not entirely true. They all have a planning clone from the original. But if the planning clone doesn't clone all of the shadow variable affected data, it's corrupted. In a multithreaded solving context this will cause issues much faster.

**Ok, this is getting complex. How do I solve this?**

Experiment with adding a `@DeepPlanningClone` annotation on your `Map` field. But making a shadow variable already implies deep planning cloning it automatically IIRC. My guess it's keys or values in that map that need to get planning cloned too. Read the planning clone section in the docs.

Comment: Now the bigger question: can OptaPlanner detect this and give a helpful error message?

Comment: "IIRC" was my problem: The docs (5.3) state that "Specifically shadow variables of type List, Set, Collection or Map usually need to be planning cloned to avoid corrupting the best solution when the working solution changes." I added @DeepPlanningClone to my Map and it worked straight out of the box.

Comment: Good point. My IIRC is wrong, but the OptaPlanner behavior is correct. A shadow variable that contains a Collection or Map could in theory be immutable or planning-immutable (think distance matrix etc), so it doesn't need to get planning cloned.

Comment: In reality however, usually it is planning mutable and needs a @DeepPlanningClone annotation. I wonder if there's a way for FULL_ASSERT to detect that the collection or map is planning mutable but not deep planning cloned.